# How to place the TextField's divider under the LeftView as well by using Cosmicmind/Material TextField

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

I am using TextField by using Material Library. That's what the default implementation(Divider is under the Text Area only).[image]

Is there any way to put the divider under the LeftView/Image and decrease the gap between Image and Text (like this).[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i don't have hands of experience on material library.. my suggestion is go with your own custom textfield

Comment: Let's see if I get any quick workaround with Material or else I will make my own custom textfield.

Answer (score 1):

this could be the solution for your problem.....

```
let leftView = UIImageView()
leftView.image = Icon.phone?.tint(with: Color.blue.base)

textField.leftView = leftView
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: No. These four lines of code produce the behavior, which `Soumen` wants to avoid. The `flavs's` solution resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the `leftView` is laid out it sets the divider's edge inset equal to it's (the `leftView`) width. So you're going to need to change that. I am subclassing `TextField`, so I just overrode `layoutSubviews`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    dividerContentEdgeInsets.left = 0
}
```